# jstl forEach loop - accessing a parent Id for the last child in an array

Tags: jsp, loops, foreach, jstl

I am going to try and simplify my example for ease of understanding the problem.

I am looping through an array which is part of a parent array. I want to be able to identify the point at which the parent array element changes when looping through the child array.

Lets say the parent array is ${bets} and the child array is ${tips}. I have 3 bets, each consisting of 3 tips. I want to be able to identify the point within the loop at which the ${bet.id} changes.

I can access the ${bet.id} from the tip element using ${tip.bet.id}

The code looks like this:

```
<c:forEach var="tip" items="${sortedTips}" varStatus="loop">
  tip ${loop.index} - ${tip.bet.id}
</c:forEach>
```

The output looks like this:

- tip 1 - 518
- tip 2 - 518
- tip 3 - 518
- tip 4 - 519
- tip 5 - 519
- tip 6 - 519
- tip 7 - 520
- tip 8 - 520
- tip 9 - 520

I want to be able to add content **in between** each new ${bet.id}, so I would like to achieve the following:

- tip 1 - 518
- tip 2 - 518
- tip 3 - 518
- **Additional Piece of content**
- tip 4 - 519
- tip 5 - 519
- tip 6 - 519
- **Additional Piece of content**
- tip 7 - 520
- tip 8 - 520
- tip 9 - 520
- **Additional Piece of content**

If it helps, I have found a way of doing this at the top of each bet with something like this:

```
<c:set var="lastBetId" value="" />
<c:forEach var="tip" items="${sortedTips}" varStatus="loop">

  <c:if test="${tip.bet.id != lastBetId}">
    Additional Piece of content <br />
  </c:if>
  <c:set var="lastBetId" value="${tip.bet.id}" />

  tip ${loop.index} - ${tip.bet.id}
</c:forEach>
```

Which results in:

- **Additional Piece of content**
- tip 1 - 518
- tip 2 - 518
- tip 3 - 518
- **Additional Piece of content**
- tip 4 - 519
- tip 5 - 519
- tip 6 - 519
- **Additional Piece of content**
- tip 7 - 520
- tip 8 - 520
- tip 9 - 520

But I cannot work out how to insert this at the bottom of each bet.

Comment: No need to do it in jsp, move the logic to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need inner loop, something like this

```
<c:set var="num" value="1" />
<c:forEach var="bet" items="${bets}" varStatus="loop">
   <c:forEach var="tip" items="${bet}" varStatus="loopInner">
      tip <c:out value="${num}" /> - ${tip.id}
      <c:set var="num" value="${num + 1}"/>
   </c:forEach>
   <!-- This is the place for additional content -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yes, this will work - and was part of a previous set up, however a request came through to remove the container loop (the bet loop in this case) so I was after a solution with just the tip loop. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this line

```
<c:if test="${tip.bet.id != lastBetId}">
Additional Piece of content <br />
```

below

```
tip ${loop.index} - ${tip.bet.id}
```

and remove

```
<c:set var="lastBetId" value="" />
```

Looks like this

```
<c:forEach var="tip" items="${sortedTips}" varStatus="loop">

tip ${loop.index} - ${tip.bet.id}
<c:set var="lastBetId" value="${tip.bet.id}" />
<c:if test="${tip.bet.id != lastBetId}">
Additional Piece of content <br />
</c:if>


</c:forEach>
```

Comment: As it is looping through 3 tips, this condition is only true after the first tip is looped, so moving it to the bottom displays the additional content underneath the first tip, rather than underneath the last (3rd) tip.

Comment: in your loop, this code `<c:set var="lastBetId" value="" />` is the one that being checked here '<c:if test="${tip.bet.id != lastBetId}"> Additional Piece of content <br /> </c:if>' before going here '<c:set var="lastBetId" value="${tip.bet.id}" />' that is why the condition becomes true and it adds the **Additional Piece of content**.